# Loop through object node with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file with something like this:

```
<itens>
<item>
  <name>Ball</name>
  <color1>Yellow</color1>
  <color2>Black</color2>
  <color3>Red</color3>
</item>

...

</itens>
```

I'm already looping it using *simplexml_load_file* and than a *foreach*. So I'm able to `echo $item->color1` and get Yellow. But what I need is to loop through those colors, something like:

```
for($x = 1; $x < 4; $x++){
  echo $item->color.$x;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Whoever created that XML format must have misunderstood something very badly about element names. However you access elements by their name in SimpleXML, and if you want to have that name in a variable, see the PHP manual. Or one of the duplicate questions (just selected one of them for you, here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13440244/367456). In the PHP manual it's here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $item->color.$x;
```

Won't work because it simply echoes `$item->color` and then appends `$x`. Try this instead

```
echo $item->{'colour'.$x};
```

Comment: I knew that my example wont work, it was just to explain. Also, thanks for the anwser. I'll check it as correct asap.