# get element from an array as a field name in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have several fields from a mysql table (width,diameter etc). Instead of building up the strings from returned data one by one

```
  $rows = $wpdb->last_result; // Wordpress version

  foreach(array_chunk($rows, 5) as $i => $pair)
  {
    $width .= "<tr><td>Width</td>";
    $diameter .= "<tr><td>Diameter</td>";
    foreach($pair as $row) 
    {   
      $width .= "<td>$row->width mm</td>";
      $diameter .= "<td>$row->diameter mm</td>";
    }

    $width .= "</tr>";
    $diameter .= "</tr>";
  }
```

Can I turn thickness,diameter,width into an array and loop over them like this:

```
  foreach(array_chunk($rows, 5) as $i => $pair)
  { 
    $measures = array("width"=>"Width","diameter"=>"Diameter","thickness"=>"Thickness","hours"=>"Hours");
    foreach($measures as $measure=>$title)
    {
        $measure .= "<td>$title</td>";
    }  

    foreach($pair as $row) 
    {   
      foreach($measures as $measure=>$title)
      {
        $measure .= "<td>$row->".$measure." mm </td>";
      }      
    }
    foreach($measures as $measure=>$title)
    {
      $measure .= "</tr>";
    }  
  }
```

But I'm getting `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` error, so is it possible to do that?

Comment: There is a missing " in the diameter .= line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed:

```
"<td>$row->".$measure." mm </td>";
```

I think the concatenation is messing it up, try like this:

```
"<td>".$row->$measure." mm </td>";
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440244/php-get-object-properties-by-variable) should be helpful.