# PHP - Use variable names with numbers through a loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, variables

In my for loop `for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)` i have have html code that will be echod 3 times. The html also using PHP objects ($help).

$help has 3 things, $help->url_1, $help->text_1, $help->icon_1. But through the loop, I want it so that when for example $i is at 2, i want to use $help->url_2, etc. How can i sort of increment the variable name in the echo string of in the loop?

Comment: You shouldn't. You should use a collection like a list or array and iterate all the items inside.

Comment: Yes, if at all possible, you should use arrays, instead of "numbered" variable or property names. But if you really have to do it this way for some reason - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - Get object properties by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440244/php-get-object-properties-by-variable)

Comment: @M.Eriksson this is close to what i want, its more that i need to put $help->url_number in a string. So im not sure how i could do $help->$var in a string..

Comment: Did you look at the answer? It does exactly what you ask for here. The first they do in the for-loop is: `$propertyName = "bullet$i";` which for you would be `$propertyName = "url_$i";` and so on for the other props. Then access it using `$help->$propertyName`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class Help
{
    public $url;
    public $text;
    public $icon;
}

$help1 = new Help();
$help1->url = 'your url';
$help1->text = 'your text';
$help1->icon = 'url to your icon';

$helps[] = $help1;

//Repeat for other helps (help2, help3, etc.)
?>
```

Once you have an array of objects, you only need to loop into it using a foreach loop :

```
foreach ($helps as $help) {
  echo "<h3>" . $help->url . "</h3>";
  echo "<p>" . $help->text . "</p>";
  echo "<img src='" . $help->icon . "' alt='your alt'/>";
}
```

Comment: This would throw "Undefined variable: $helps". Your code doesn't create it or show how they should to it. Either way, it doesn't actually answer the question. We don't know if it's possible for them to use arrays instead or not.